# Chrome dev tools shortcut overrides Google docs shortcut

Tags: google-chrome, google-sheets, google-chrome-devtools, google-docs

I am using Chrome on OSX.

Chrome developer tools has a shortcut <kbd>CMD</kbd> <kbd>OPTION</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> which activates "Select node to inspect" function of chrome developer tools.

The same <kbd>CMD</kbd> <kbd>OPTION</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> shortcut is used in Google Docs for "Copy formatting".

When I use <kbd>CMD</kbd> <kbd>OPTION</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> shortcut in Google Docs, it only activates Chrome developer tools, but "Copy formatting" is not performed.

Both, Google Docsand Chrome does not allow to change these shortcuts...

I have found that it is possible to disable Chrome developer tools, but I would like to keep an option to quickly activate developer tools, since I might need to use it occasionally.

Comment: There's no solution, probably. You can report this problem on a google forum for Docs. In the future devtools will allow to customize shortcuts, see https://crbug.com/174309.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

**Copy format**: <kbd>CMD</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> (just like normal)

**Paste format**: <kbd>CMD</kbd> <kbd>OPTION</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd>

You can check this shortcut in the Menu Tabs when you go to "**Edit**" > "**Paste special**" > "**Paste format only**"

Comment: Perfect. Silly mistake of Google. Often their different dev teams don't communicate well with each other.